# Flask-SQLAlchemy & Flask-Marshmallow Order with items serialization

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-marshmallow

For a restaurant application I am trying to set up a Schema in SQLAlchemy with orders and orderlines per order. I am using Flask-SQLAlchemy for the model creation and Flask-Marshmallow for the serialization.

I would like to retrieve all orders for a specific table and show the orderlines with their product information. The table information is showing on the JSON result of the order but table has a 1 to 1 relationship with order and the orderlines have a many to 1 relationship with order. How could I can show the orderlines and their information in the order by using the foreign key of order in the orderlines table?

**Imports and setup**

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_marshmallow import Marshmallow

app = Flask(__name__)
basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = "sqlite:///" + \
    os.path.join(basedir, 'restuarant.db')
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
ma = Marshmallow(app)
```

**SQLAlchemy Models Order, Orderlines, Table & Product**

```
class Order(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'Orders'
    order_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    order_date = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow)
    total_price = db.Column(db.Float)
    table_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey(
        'Tables.table_id'), nullable=False)
    order_items = db.relationship(
        'Order_item', backref=db.backref('order', lazy='joined'))

class Order_item(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'Order_items'
    order_item_id = db.Column(
        db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    quantity = db.Column(db.Integer)
    order_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey(
        'Orders.order_id'))  # nullable = False
    product_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey(
        'Products.product_id'))  # nullable = False

class Table(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'Tables'
    table_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    table_name = db.Column(db.String(20))
    orders = db.relationship(
        'Order', backref=db.backref('table', lazy='joined'))

class Product(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'Products'
    product_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    product_name = db.Column(db.String(50))
    description = db.Column(db.String(250))
    price = db.Column(db.Float)
    order_items = db.relationship(
        'Order_item', backref=db.backref('product', lazy='joined'))
```

**Marshmallow Schemas**

```
class ProductSchema(ma.SQLAlchemySchema):
    class Meta:
        model = Product

    # Fields to expose
    product_id = ma.auto_field()
    product_name = ma.auto_field()
    description = ma.auto_field()
    price = ma.auto_field()


product_schema = ProductSchema()
products_schema = ProductSchema(many=True)


class TableSchema(ma.SQLAlchemySchema):
    class Meta:
        model = Table

    # Fields to expose
    table_id = ma.auto_field()
    table_name = ma.auto_field()


table_schema = TableSchema()
tables_schema = TableSchema(many=True)


class Order_ItemSchema(ma.SQLAlchemySchema):
    class Meta:
        model = Order_item

    # Fields to expose
    order_item_id = ma.auto_field()
    quantity = ma.auto_field()
    item_status = ma.auto_field()

    product = ma.Nested(ProductSchema)


order_item_schema = Order_ItemSchema()
order_items_schema = Order_ItemSchema(many=True)


class OrderSchema(ma.SQLAlchemySchema):
    class Meta:
        model = Order

    # Fields to expose
    order_id = ma.auto_field()
    order_date = ma.auto_field()
    total_price = ma.auto_field()

    #How to set up the items schema in Marshmallow?
    items = ma.List(ma.Nested(lambda: Order_ItemSchema()))
    table = ma.Nested(TableSchema)


order_schema = OrderSchema()
orders_schema = OrderSchema(many=True)
```

**Route for order**

```
@ app.route("/orders", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def orders():
    if request.method == "POST":
        pass
    else:
        orders = Order.query.filter_by(table_id=1).all()
        return jsonify(orders_schema.dump(orders))
```

**JSON output**

```
[
  {
    "order_date": "2022-04-10T13:34:33.891639", 
    "order_id": 1, 
    "table": {
      "table_id": 1, 
      "table_name": "Test table"
    }, 
    "total_price": 4.04
  }, 
  {
    "order_date": "2022-04-10T19:10:48.735628", 
    "order_id": 2, 
    "table": {
      "table_id": 1, 
      "table_name": "Test table"
    }, 
    "total_price": 2.02
  }
]
```

**Wanted Result**

```
[
  {
    "order_date": "2022-04-10T13:34:33.891639", 
    "order_id": 1, 
    "table": {
      "table_id": 1, 
      "table_name": "Test table"
    },
    "items": [
        {
            "order_item_id": 1,
            "quantity": 2,
            "order_id": 1,
            "product_id": 1
        },
        {
            "order_item_id": 2,
            "quantity": 4,
            "order_id": 1,
            "product_id": 2
        }
    ],
    "total_price": 4.04
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

After seeing [the example of serializing a join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72436344/how-to-serialize-sql-data-after-a-join-using-marshmallow-flask-extension), I managed to use backref "order" on the Order_item class with the attribute field in the marshmallow Nested method to retrieve the order items.

```
class OrderSchema(ma.SQLAlchemySchema):
    class Meta:
        model = Order

    # Fields to expose
    order_id = ma.auto_field()
    order_date = ma.auto_field()
    total_price = ma.auto_field()

    items = ma.Nested(order_items_schema, attribute='order')
    table = ma.Nested(TableSchema)


order_schema = OrderSchema()
orders_schema = OrderSchema(many=True)
```

Result:

```
  {
    "items": [
      {
        "item_status": "Ordered", 
        "order_item_id": 1, 
        "product": {
          "description": "Nice test product 1", 
          "price": 1.01, 
          "product_id": 1, 
          "product_name": "Test product 1"
        }, 
        "quantity": 1
      }, 
      {
        "item_status": "Ordered", 
        "order_item_id": 2, 
        "product": {
          "description": "Nice test product 2", 
          "price": 2.02, 
          "product_id": 2, 
          "product_name": "Test product 2"
        }, 
        "quantity": 4
      }
    ], 
    "order_date": "2022-07-03T10:11:56.229125", 
    "order_id": 1, 
    "table": {
      "table_id": 1, 
      "table_name": "Test table"
    }, 
    "total_price": 9.09
  }
```